# Can I random to show SizeBox widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to show SizeBox widget by random. when I open this class it should be random to show Size Box 1 first or Size Box 2 first.

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {

  var random = new Random();
  int randomNumber;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[

                  randomNumber = random.nextInt(1);

if(randomNumber == 1){

/////////////////////////////////////// Size box 1 ////////////////////////////////////
                  SizedBox(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {

                          
                          AlertDialog(
                              title: Text('a'),
                              content: Text('a'));
                        },
                        child: Image.asset('images/test.jpg'),
                      )),
}else{

/////////////////////////////////////// Size box 2 ////////////////////////////////////
                  SizedBox(
                     
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          AlertDialog(
                              title: Text('b'),
                              content: Text('b'));
                        },
                        child: Image.asset('images/test2.jpg'),
                      )),
}
```

I try to use `randomNumber = random.nextInt(1)` in `children: <Widget>[]` but it show

```
The element type 'int' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.dart(list_element_type_not_assignable)
```

It seems I cannot write dart code in widget. Can I random to show SizeBox widget ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you called `randomNumber = random.nextInt(1);` inside the Row children. Since `randomNumber` is of type `int` and not of type `Widget` you can't do this. One way to fix this is to create a [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and set the `randomNumber` in [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) method.
By the way using `if/else` inside `children` of Row/Column you don't put the curly brackets `{}`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page createState() => _Page();
}

class _Page extends State<Page> {
  var random = new Random();
  int randomNumber;

  @override
  void initState(){
    randomNumber = random.nextInt(1);
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  if (randomNumber == 1)
/////////////////////////////////////// Size box 1 ////////////////////////////////////
                    SizedBox(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          AlertDialog(title: Text('a'), content: Text('a'));
                        },
                        child: Image.asset('images/test.jpg'),
                      ),
                    )
                  else
/////////////////////////////////////// Size box 2 ////////////////////////////////////
                    SizedBox(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          AlertDialog(title: Text('b'), content: Text('b'));
                        },
                        child: Image.asset('images/test2.jpg'),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```